# How to fix code: 'ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK' nodejs

Tags: node.js

I'm very new to nodejs. I've been following a udemy instructor and after copying and understanding what he demonstrated, my compiler gives me an 'ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK' error. Please help me understand. Thank you!

```
const fs = require('fs');

if(!fs.exists("views")){

    fs.mkdir("views", (err)=>{

        if(err) return err;

        fs.writeFile("./views/new.html", 'this is a new dir and data', (err)=>{

            if (err) return err;

            console.log('Directory and File saved!')
        })
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like [`fs.mkdir`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_mkdir_path_options_callback) and [`fs.writeFile`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback), the method [`fs.exists`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_exists_path_callback) is async and expects a callback. If you want to "wait" for it to finish, use [`fs.existsSync()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_existssync_path):

```js
const fs = require('fs');

if(!fs.existsSync("views")){

    fs.mkdir("views", (err)=>{

        if(err) return err;

        fs.writeFile("./views/new.html", 'this is a new dir and data', (err)=>{

            if (err) return err;

            console.log('Directory and File saved!')
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: i get it now! i was wondering if which among the callback functions i wrote wrongly. thank you very much kind sir!